# Azure Management API - Create VMImage - InvalidXmlRequest - The request body XML was invalid or not correctly specified

Tags: c#, xml, rest, azure, iaas

I'm hoping someone can put me in the right direction regarding creating a VM Image via the service management REST API. Everything I've tried has led me to get back a 400 InvalidXmlRequest error which states that "The request body's XML was invalid or not correctly specified."

Assume that I have a properly provisioned subscription, storage account, container, and blob. I've been sending a properly authenticated POST request with the x-ms-version: 2014-06-01 header to the https://management.core.windows.net/[OmittedSubscriptionId]/services/vmimages API with the following XM in the body:

```
<VMImages xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <VMImage>
        <Name>my_image_20141120_service_sa01</Name>
        <Label>my_Image_20141120_service_SA01</Label>
        <Description>testimage</Description>
        <OSDiskConfiguration>
            <HostCaching>ReadWrite</HostCaching>
            <OSState>Specialized</OSState>
            <OS>Windows</OS>
            <MediaLink>https://myservicesa.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/myimage_20141120.vhd</MediaLink>
        </OSDiskConfiguration>
    </VMImage>
</VMImages>
```

Per the instructions here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn775054.aspx, I've specified all the required bits so I’m not sure what is invalid about the xml I'm sending. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried loading the Azure Dashboard in a browser, running Fiddler to see what the browser is doing, and creating a VM Image via the Dashboard?  You also don't state what versions of the Azure SDK you are using.  I don't remember the specifics but later versions of the SDK had some changes in the Blob URL that we had to change.  Something like wanting a relative URL not a fully qualified URL.

Comment: browser will do slightly different requests, as it does not call management API directly, but via a server-side proxies. So what is sent from the browser is no related to service management API. However PowerShell cmdlets are doing direct management API calls. So tracing a PowerShell cmdlet will give you a clean picture.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is incorrect and we apologize for any inconvenience this caused. The request should work if you change it to:

```
<VMImage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Name>my_image_20141120_service_sa01</Name>
    <Label>my_Image_20141120_service_SA01</Label>
    <Description>testimage</Description>
    <OSDiskConfiguration>
        <HostCaching>ReadWrite</HostCaching>
        <OSState>Specialized</OSState>
        <OS>Windows</OS>
        <MediaLink>https://myservicesa.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/myimage_20141120.vhd</MediaLink>
    </OSDiskConfiguration>
</VMImage>
```

There are two types of images that can be used to create virtual machines. OS Images are always generalized and do not maintain a previous state of the originating machine. VM Images can be specialized and maintain the state of attached data disks.

There are two sets of REST operations that can be used [Operations on Operating System Images](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj157175.aspx) and [Operations on Virtual Machine Images](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn499771.aspx).

When using PowerShell, I believe that you use Add-AzureVMImage to create an OS Image and you use Save-AzureVMImage with the -OSState parameter to create a VM Image.

Also not mentioned in the documentation, is that the Create VM Image operation is asynchronous, so the Get Operation Status operation needs to be used to get the status of the image creation. The documentation will be corrected soon.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks astaykov, looking at the traffic from PowerShell was an excellent idea. Turns out the documentation is totally wrong for this API! Not only is the XML payload completely different, the API itself is different. The actual API endpoint that needs to get called is:

```
https://management.core.windows.net/[OmittedSubscriptionId]/services/images
```

Note it's "images" vs "vmimages"

The body of the POST should be as follows:

```
<OSImage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure">
    <Label>identifier-of-image</Label>
    <MediaLink>uri-to-vhd</MediaLink>
    <Name>name-of-image</Name>
    <OS>Opearting-System</OS>
    <IsPremium>bool</IsPremium>
    <ShowInGui>bool</ShowInGui>
</OSImage>
```

Comment: Interesting finding. I am really surprised by the shocking difference in the XML payload and the endpoint reference :(

Comment: This is incorrect, OS Image is different than a VM Image.

Comment: @proteus I agree with you on principle but that's not what actually is working right now. Try yourself to create a new VMImage using the documented process. It simply won't work. Also make a call to Add-AzureVMImage in PowerShell and you'll see that the POST it makes to create a new image is done with an OSImage and not a VMImage. That's what makes this all the more confusing. In any case doing it this way works great for me now so I'm moving on with this solution.

Comment: I see your point. Looking at the source of the commandlet at https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-tools/blob/cd8e3e0be65010db44b40d70bf16a52df44981a2/src/ServiceManagement/Compute/Commands.ServiceManagement/IaaS/DiskRepository/AddAzureVMImage.cs it looks like it does not support VMImage as yet. You can use the payload I mention below to create a VMImage if you prefer that.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the payload as such and it should work.

> ```
> <VMImage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
>     <Name>my_image_20141120_service_sa01</Name>
>     <Label>my_Image_20141120_service_SA01</Label>
>     <Description>testimage</Description>
>     <OSDiskConfiguration>
>         <HostCaching>ReadWrite</HostCaching>
>         <OSState>Specialized</OSState>
>         <OS>Windows</OS>
>         <MediaLink>https://myservicesa.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/myimage_20141120.vhd</MediaLink>
>     </OSDiskConfiguration>
> </VMImage>
> ```

POST it on

> https://management.core.windows.net/[OmittedSubscriptionId]/services/vmimages